# An ajax jump menu using Drupal views?

Tags: 7, views

I've got a Drupal view that contains a jumplist of items filtered by taxonomy (which is pulled from the current page URL).

The problem is that I need this jumplist to work without a page reload (so using AJAX).

I've tried a few different things and done a lot of Googling, but come up with nothing.

I've read that you can expose filters to users and use this for Ajax filtering, the problem with this seems to be that you can't populate a select element with values from the database when using a filter, it looks like the filter values have to be hard coded or user defined, so this looks like a no go.

Is there any way of accomplishing this? Or am I going about this in the wrong way?

Comment: How is your view set up right now? Are you using contextual filters?

Comment: I am to set the taxonomy yes.

Comment: Ok, so you are getting the tax term from the URL which is populating the jumplist. Then the user can change the tax term to repopulate the jumplist?

Comment: Sorry, yes, that's correct!

Comment: Hmm, right now I have a view set up as a Jump menu with an exposed filter (Content: Has taxonomy term(exposed)) with Ajax and a tax ID contextual filter and it works fine. Perhaps you can share a screen shot?

Comment: It's not the taxonomy switch that needs to be ajax, it's the changing of the item selected via the jumplist, e.g. the jumplist displays titles, a new title is selected from the jumplist, and the content updates without reloading the page (it doesn't have to be a jumplist, I'm happy to implement this with filters, or in another way)

Comment: Does that make sense? If not I can get a screenshot together

Comment: Screenshots would help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% on your desired set up but there are a couple of ways that I can think of to get the functionality that I believe you want. If you have a view with filters and displays that also includes a jumplist (the jumplist is just a part of your desired view) I would suggest adding an attachment to your view. This attachment can share contextual and exposed filters.